# Encrypting/Decrypting JWE with Jose in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a JWE decryption function but having trouble determining how to use the Go Jose interface for doing so. I've factored the encryption using passphrase (I prefer a passphrase for this use case):

```
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(
        jwt.SigningMethodHS256,
        claims,
    )
    ss, err := token.SignedString("thisisatestpassphraserighthere")
    if err != nil {
        panic("COULD_NOT_GENERATE")
        return
    }
    privateKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    publicKey := &privateKey.PublicKey
    encrypter, err := jose.NewEncrypter(
        jose.A128CBC_HS256,
        jose.Recipient{Algorithm: jose.RSA_OAEP, Key: publicKey},
        nil,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    object, err := encrypter.Encrypt([]byte(ss))
    if err != nil {
        errRes = s.Error(codes.Internal, err, nil)
        return
    }
    key, err := object.CompactSerialize()
    if err != nil {
        errRes = s.Error(codes.Internal, err, nil)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(key)
```

The above code creates a JWT, encodes it, compacts it and returns the key. It's not however totally clear how to decrypt it with the passphrase now.

There is an example for JWE on the Jose docs: https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2#example-Encrypter--Encrypt

So I've factored this:

```
    object, err = jose.ParseEncrypted(Key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    decrypted, err := object.Decrypt(...)
```

Inside the ellipses I'm not sure what to put though. I can't seem to determine how to pass in a key based on passphrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was doing a few things wrong it seems. First of all rsa.GenerateKey uses a randomized value. This was totally wrong :-p the following is how you can encrypt a JWT into a JWE using a token:

```
rcpt := jose.Recipient{
    Algorithm:  jose.PBES2_HS256_A128KW,
    Key:        "mypassphrase",
    PBES2Count: 4096,
    PBES2Salt: []byte{ your salt... },
}
enc, err := jose.NewEncrypter(jose.A128CBC_HS256, rcpt, nil)
if err != nil {
   panic("oops")
}
jewPlaintextToken, err := enc.Encrypt(jwtToken)
if err != nil {
    panic("oops")
}
key, err := object.CompactSerialize()
if err != nil {
    panic("oops")
}
```

This is how you decrypt:

```
// Decrypt the receive key
jwe, err := jose.ParseEncrypted(jewPlaintextToken)
if err != nil {
    panic("oops")
}
decryptedKey, err := jwe.Decrypt("mypassphrase")
if err != nil {
    panic("oops")
}
```

If anyone sees any major problems/security issues with this method, please mention it.

Answer (score 2):

> Inside the ellipses I'm not sure what to put though. I can't seem to determine how to pass in a key based on passphrase.

From the `JWE` example in the documentation, you must pass the private key. See the below part for decryption

https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2#JSONWebEncryption.Decrypt

```
// Generate a public/private key pair to use for this example.
privateKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Parse the serialized, encrypted JWE object. An error would indicate that
// the given input did not represent a valid message.
object, err = ParseEncrypted(serialized)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Now we can decrypt and get back our original plaintext. An error here
// would indicate the the message failed to decrypt, e.g. because the auth
// tag was broken or the message was tampered with.
decrypted, err := object.Decrypt(privateKey)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf(string(decrypted))
```